# Define return type of a function in dictionary based on its parameter in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a function that shall return different objects depending on the function parameter.
Is there a way how I can achieve this in Typescript?

This is how far I have got:

```
type returnMap = {
    'a': number,
    'b': string[]
}

function func<T extends returnMap, K extends keyof T>(val: K): T[K] {
    if (val == 'a') {return 5}
    if (val == 'b') {return ['a', 'b']}
    return 42
}
console.log(func('a'))  // 5
```

However, it says "TS2322: Type '5' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'" at the return values.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do:

```
interface ReturnMap {
  'a': number;
  'b': string[];
}

function func<K extends keyof ReturnMap>(val: K): ReturnMap[K];
function func(val: keyof ReturnMap): ReturnMap[keyof ReturnMap] {
  if (val === 'a') return 5;
  if (val === 'b') return ['a', 'b'];
  throw new Error();
}

const r1 = func('a'); // const r1: number
const r2 = func('b'); // const r2: string[]

// Argument of type '"c"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a" | "b"'.ts(2345)
const r3 = func('c'); // const r3: number | string[]
```

Notice the function overloading syntax:

```
function func<K extends keyof ReturnMap>(val: K): ReturnMap[K];
function func(val: keyof ReturnMap): ReturnMap[keyof ReturnMap] { // ...
```

If you only used second signature, then returned type would be always `number | string[]`.

If you only used first signature, then `ReturnMap[K]` is evaluated (inside function's body) as `number & string[]` which is contravariant, so you get the errors which you described in your question above.

Alternatively, if you do not want to use overloaded signature - you may cast the result inside function's body:

```
function func<K extends keyof ReturnMap>(val: K): ReturnMap[K] {
  if (val === 'a') return 5 as ReturnMap[K];
  if (val === 'b') return ['a', 'b'] as ReturnMap[K];
  throw new Error();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tomasz. This indeed works! Did not know that something like function overloading existed or that this could solve my problem.

Comment: Hi @Tomasz Gawel, I'm unable to reproduce `If you only used first signature, then ReturnMap[K] is evaluated as number & string[]`. Could You please tell me how to reproduce it?

Comment: @captain-yossarian I meant inside function's body.

Comment: It does not look future proof to me. Although, it works for OP. From the question, it seems like the OP wants to have a return type that accommodates `K extends T[keyof T]` where `T extends ReturnValue`. so the return type may be not just `number | string[]` but it should also accommodate all types of values in `T extends ReturnValue`

Comment: @Nishant With this approach You could write general signature for any type (I mean "return map" passed as generic parameter) but as this is function implementation, you could not provide actual implementation for any type ;).

Comment: consider this case: [See this typescript payground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShwFcBOA7AsgQzFAvFA3gFBQlQDkGZAXFCggLYBGESANMaWY9VAM7BIAligDmAbQC6hAL6FCAYwD2KflCTxk6LAFEAHsFwEOJCjwCMAJgDM7UuW40xZMGVbkAjmQm3OungCI9YAgUABMIUP8ZOUIAMwQUeWBBZSh4xIAeABUoCH0Q0N5YDVRMMDcAaVz8sKKAawgQRVioLIA+AAoANwwAGxoKgEoaLLEKiSM7QRbuvtw8U0GCdURUKABWWSmZnt75+zIl-BXNKCdKNy4vLdITtbutMCCxXYkAbmilFUVeiAA6XqKEQddLyDqLJZQAD0UI2QA) My return type is derived based on the keys T which extends ReturnMap.

Comment: @Tomasz, this is not buggy behaviour, this is intended . Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type

Comment: @captain-yossarian your are right it's not buggy, intersection is OK, and as consequence you may cast it to ReturnMap[K] inside the function's body.

Answer (score 1):

I think overloading might help You:

```js
type returnMap = {
    'a': number,
    'b': string[],
    'x': 42,
    'z': 42,
}

function func<T extends returnMap, K extends Exclude<keyof returnMap,'a'|'b'>>(val: K): 42;
function func<T extends returnMap, K extends 'b'>(val: K): string[];
function func<T extends returnMap, K extends 'a'>(val: K): number;
function func<T extends returnMap, K extends keyof T>(val: K): number | string[] {
    if (val == 'a') {
        return 5
    }
    if (val == 'b') {
        return ['a', 'b']
    }
    return 42
}

const result = func('a') // number
const result1 = func('b') // string[]
const result2 = func('x') // 42
const result3 = func('z') // 42
```

Comment: This works too but seems a bit more complex than the solution of Tomasz. However, there may be a reason for this (?)

Comment: @Nayaro Tomasz's solution is a bit better, because it more generic than my. Feel free to use his solution. Just make sure You are aware about function overloads https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a good use case for using `any` as the returned variable’s type.

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any.

Comment: I think the thought process in the question is `T[K]` is `number | string[]`. So, why does the compiler complain when the code is returning `number | string[]`.

Comment: That is my current solution to solve this problem. However, I would like to provide more convenience and type safety.
The use case is that this method makes some API calls and returns different objects depending on the URL which is given as val here.

Comment: `any` considered as a bad practice. There are only few cases where it might help and I don't know nothing about them )